# Planning an oversized deck

Tags: deck, construction, design, decking

we are planning on building an oversized deck 50 foot long, 18 foot wide, 9 foot high

Using  2x12x18 southern pine decking joist.

Planning on spacing  post 6 foot apart.

I’m looking for advice with design and materials to ensure a safe long lasting deck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is rather broad in scope and any answer regarding design and materials is subjective - ie - opinion based.  This site focuses on specific questions with definitive answers.  As such, opinion based questions are really off topic for us.

Answer (score 1):

Your local building codes will be the ultimate guide, and depending on your location, you'll likely need a permit and inspection as well.

This may help you with your estimating:  https://www.awc.org/codes-standards/publications/dca6

Having just built a 16x12 deck ten feet off the ground, 50x18 would be lot of work and not cheap.